# Reverse the JSON array

Tags: java, json, csv

```
String jsonString="{"name":"event_level_count","elements":[{"serial_number":"xxx12315","manufacturer_name":"xxx","count_level1":2004,"count_level2":1798,"count_level3":7},{"serial_number":"yyx01444","manufacturer_name":"xxx","count_level1":15,"count_level2":11,"count_level3":3}]}" ;
    JSONObject output = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("elements");
    System.out.println("Docs: "+docs);
```

Output Docs:

```
    {"name":"event_level_count","elements":[{"count_level3":7,"count_level2":1798,"count_level1":2004,"manufacturer_name":"xxx","serial_number":"xxx12315"},{"count_level3":3,"count_level2":11,"count_level1":15,"manufacturer_name":"xxx","serial_number":"yyx01444"}]}

    File file=new File("path \\ExportAsExcelfromJSON.csv");
    String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
```

I need to reverse its as given string - jsonString.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Why do you need to reverse the JSON array and not the array in the code?

Comment: I just need as i passing like "jsonString"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is simply a way to save or transfer data -- if you care about how it looks (e.g. how it's sorted), you are probably doing something wrong. If you want the array to be sorted in any way, do it once you have parsed the JSON back into actual data. Most programming languages (Java, for instance) come with easy-to-use tools to sort arrays.

As per Nizil's comment and [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29), you can use the `reverse(List<?> list)` function from the `Collections` class in Java.

Comment: For example: [Collections#reverse(List<?> list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))

Comment: Thanks, @Nizil. I've added that to the post.